# Want to increase height of ngSelect options

Tags: css, angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Form Image:
[image: Form Image]

Currently `ng-select` is only showing 5 items. I want to increase the height of dropdown so that it can show 8-10 items. I'm using the below code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="addReportForm" class="form-horizontal col-xs-12" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="adb-name">Name</label>
    <input  id="adb-name" class="form-control text-16-normal" type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="adb-report">Type</label>
    <ng-select
      id="adb-report"
      [items]="allReports"
      [multiple]="false"
      [closeOnSelect]="true"
      [searchable]="true"
      bindLabel="name"
      bindValue="id"
      formControlName="vizType"
      placeholder="Select Report"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
      [(ngModel)]="reportName"
    >
    </ng-select>
  </div>
  <app-alert></app-alert>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the **height** with `css`:

```
.ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
    max-height: 500px !important;
}
```

default `max-height` for `ng-select` is `240px`

Comment: Did you add this in your styles.scss file or component style file?

Comment: styles.scss file

Comment: try adding `!important` to the style.

Comment: Yes it's working Thanks!! but how can i make it only for a particular component

Comment: You can also add these style in component 'scss' file by adding them inside `::ng-deep{}`

Comment: and I would be glad if my answer helped you to solve your problem, accept it :)

Comment: ` ::ng-deep  .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
  .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
    max-height: 420px !important;
}
}`
It is still updating css globally

Answer (score 1):

You have  to use /deep/ more the component that you want change.

```
/deep/ .ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items {
max-height: 500px;   }
```